# How to custom "mediaplayer" template in xcode for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: media-player

The case is I am playing a live video in my APPS, I need to add a "REC" button in to the "mediaplayer" template.

Would you please tell me how can I custom "mediaplayer" template in xcode for iPhone/iPad?

or am I need to disable the preset menu and build a new menu for this case?

I had search in internet, but haven't find anythings about it.

Thank you for your help!